# What is the default value for thread-stacksize in uWSGI?

Tags: flask, uwsgi

The options don't specify defaults in their docs: https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Options.html#thread-stacksize.

I'm considering adding `thread-stacksize=512`to my uwsgi config since it seems to resolve a segfault issue I've been having, but I want to know what the original setting was first.

Edit: Through trial and error, I ended up using 128 for the stack size. At 64, I was seeing my specific issue. I'm going to assume the default is 64 or less.

Answer (score 0):

Uwsgi gets it from the operating system.

- 1 MB default stack size on Windows
- 8 MB default stack size on Unix/Linux platforms

On linux you can check this using **ulimit** command

> ulimit  -s

-> output 8192 (in kbytes)